# iOS: Silencing Device in xCode

Tags: ios, audio

We were creating an app that requires us to silence the notifications and ringers of our device. When the app is being used it must silence the device, and when it is done it needs to restore the volume and sounds.

We've thought of three ways to do this. We would like our app to be approved by the App store.

1. AVSystemController -> not approved
2. Setting a silent audio file as ringtone and notification
3. Tricking the device into thinking the headphones are plugged in.

Any suggestions? This is the biggest obstacle we've had.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be achieved.

I believe even if you find someway to overcome this issue, probably/definitely apple will reject it.

According to Apple's Review Guidelines

> 10.5 Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, will be rejected

Comment: And for really good security reasons.  Were the OP's request possible, it there would be lots of nefarious uses to which it could be put.